# Decrease the space between header and paragraph vertically in html

Tags: html, css

I want to decrease the vertical spacing between header and paragraph.

```
<td style="width:427px;">
  <h2 style="color:#156CA4">Quotation</h2>
  <p style="color:#00A651">abc Technologies Pvt Ltd</p>
</td>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try adjusting the line height property using CSS. I would recommend giving it an id though if you only want it to affect this p tag in particular

```
p {
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

There is also the possibility of negative margins (which isn't considered best practice, but will work in your case):

```
p {
    margin-top:-5px;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You have to remove the margin from both h2 and p.

```
    h2{
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    p{
      margin-top: 0;
    }
```

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/539qdkrg/) is a jsfiddle to see the results

Comment: Well... This is better solution than accepted, if your paragraph or header spans multiple lines,

Answer (score 3):

Simple use following css will remove default all padding and margin. Because here h2 use default spacing.

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Previous result:

```html
 <td style="width:427px;">
 <h2 style="color:#156CA4">Quotation</h2>
 <p style="color:#00A651">abc Technologies Pvt Ltd</p>
 </td>
```

New working Result:

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
 <td style="width:427px;">
 <h2 style="color:#156CA4">Quotation</h2>
 <p style="color:#00A651">abc Technologies Pvt Ltd</p>
 </td>
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcyhgt2q/)**

Answer (score 2):

Use margin-bottom style inside h2

```
margin-bottom:-10px;
```

To decrease space we should use values in negative.

Answer (score 2):

Add this style below your html, i thing it can be usefull

```
<style>
    h2, p {
       margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: This will apply the style to all <p> elements that are children of <h2>. To apply the style to just the first element after the header, h2 + p {...}  should be used. This applies the style to only the sibling <p> of <h2>.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

```
h2 + p {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Which makes paragraphs that immediately follow an H2 headline have a top margin of 0.

You may also have to alter the bottom margin of the headline.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Setting Line height on the p and all heading tag works for me.

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p{
   margin: 0;  // if there is margin
   padding:0;  // if there is padding
  line-height: 0px !important; // you should set line height according to your requirement.
}
```

This will affect all children's components.